# change Pivot direction to Right-To-Left in Universal Windows Project

Tags: visual-studio, pivot, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I opened a UWP project in Visual Studio 2015(Community).

I added a Pivot from the Tool-Box.
How do I change the direction of  and  to be from Right to Left in order to type Hebrew titles and text?

The given code in the project display the titles left-to-right while Hebrew should be direct to right to left.

Note: I try to search and get an answer here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/078fd0c6-8262-4497-82d0-aeedccb65c9a/uwpw10xamlc-uwp-calendar-pivot-issues?forum=wpdevelop, but still - nothing.

I'll appreciate any help and guide.

Comment: Check the online help forum for these questions. Its very basic concept which you can easily find answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add to `<Pivot>` tag the property `FlowDirection`

Comment: It would be useful if you add also possible values of `FlowDirection` property or some examples.